# AudioRecorder getminbuffersize not always returns the same values

Tags: android, audio

I am developing an Android Application to process audio. To know the possibles configurations supported by the device I do a manual algorithm that I see in this forum. In concret:

```
for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
            for (short audioFormat : aformats) {
                for (short channelConfig : chConfigs) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("Log:", "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: "
                                + audioFormat + ", channel: " + channelConfig);
                        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate,
                                channelConfig, audioFormat);

                        if (bufferSize > 0) {

                            AudioRecord recorder2 = new AudioRecord(
                                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, rate,
                                    channelConfig, audioFormat,
                                    java.lang.Math.max(bufferSize, 1024 * 800));

                            if (recorder2.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                                auxicapture = new StructCapture();
                                auxicapture.setfrequency(rate);
                                auxicapture.setencoding(audioFormat);
                                auxicapture.setchannel(channelConfig);
                                captureoptions.add(aux, auxicapture);

                                aux++;
                                recorder2.release();

                            }

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Log:", rate + "Exception, keep trying.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But every time that I use this algoritm returns differents values and sometimes the programs produces an error.
So my question is, do you know other way to check this.

thanks